# Add parenthesis to statement

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I am having an issue parsing a string and adding parenthesis to it in Python. One of my issues is that the string may be input in a fully parenthesized manner (ie `(01U(1U0))`) or it may be none at all (ie `01U1U0`). The grammar that I cannot seem to split it on is:

```
A -> e* | (eUe)
e -> any combination of chars from the grammar
```

The `e*` has higher precedence and than the `U`.

Hopefully this makes sense. Anyone have any ideas how I can parse through and check parenthesis?

Comment: Your grammar doesn't allow "U" when there is no parenthesis. Why not just A -> e* | (A) ? I don't understand your question though... are you searching for a parser ? a parser generator ? or a way to manually parse ?

Comment: It doesn't allow for it without U that is correct, that is why I need to add the parenthesis. I am looking for a manual way to parse through it

Comment: Then, you'll have to write your own [push down automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton), traversing the string from left to right, and putting into the stack at least the left operand of U while you are analysing the remainder of the string until you parsed the right operand of the U.

Comment: I thought you could only do a PDA if the string was already correctly formatted. Is there an easy way to create the PDA you described in python?

Comment: When you write a parser, your program is the PDA. Perhaps the simplest way is to write it is to have one function for each symbol in the left side of your grammar. (there, "A" and "e") This function will read the string at the current character, and depending on the characters it reads, will consume those characters or will call other functions. For instance, you'll have a function rule_A(), which will look the first character: if  it is a parenthesis, then il will call rule_e() check that there is a "U", and call rule_e() another time ; if there is no parenthesis, it will just call rule_e()

Comment: Ok, I wrote out his code: http://pastebin.com/J9RUvkdb but I fell as though I am missing something, how do I tell it when the index has reached the end and should be closing? Am I missing something huge?

Comment: This is not exactly what I was thinking about. Here, your openCount, is your stack. Thus, you don't really need to use multiple functions. Functions would be usefull if you intend to use your program stack as your automaton stack. I'll try to explain it better later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is probably the simplest way to write a parser from a LL grammar is to have one function per non-terminal symbol. This function should eat the characters from the input string corresponding to one reduction of the rules. Below is the parser corresponding to the grammar

```
A -> e+ | '(' A 'U' A ')'
e -> '0' | '1'
```

This is not exactly the grammar you wanted, but it was more relevent from the examples you gave. The grammar is LL(1), you just need to read one character to know how to proceed. The following parser defines two functions A() and e() for those two non-terminal symbols :

```
class MySyntaxError(Exception):
  def __init__(self, text, index):
    self.text = text 
    self.index = index
  def __str__(self):
    return "Syntax error at index " + repr(self.index) + ": " + self.text


def parse(input):
  global index
  index = 0

  def eat_char(set):
    global index
    if index < len(input) and input[index] in set:
      index += 1
    else:
      raise MySyntaxError("expected char in " + repr(set), index)

  def e():
    eat_char(['0', '1'])

  def A():
    global index
    if index == len(input): # Successfully parsed
      return
    elif input[index] in ['0', '1']:
      while (input[index] in ['0', '1']):
        e()
    elif input[index] is '(':
      eat_char(['('])
      A()
      eat_char(['U'])
      A()
      eat_char([')'])
    else:
      raise MySyntaxError("expected char '0', '1' or '('", index)

  A()
  if index != len(input): # Parsing didn't reach the end of the string
    raise MySyntaxError("parsing ended before the end of the input", index)


def test(string):
  try:
    parse(string)
    print "The string " + string + " have been successfully parsed"
  except MySyntaxError as e:
    print "The string " + string + " can't be parsed:"
    print e

test("(01U(1U0))")
test("(01U(1U0)") # Missing parenthesis, syntax error
test("(01U(1U0)))") # Too many parenthesis, syntax error
test("01U(1U0)") # No parenthesis, syntax error
```

Note taht using e* instead of e+ makes empty reducing to A which complicates the parser.

The push-down automata is hidden in the parser. o build the automaton from the grammar is not so simple. Here, the PDA have only one state. We can describe the automaton this way:

```
from state [1]
  read a '0' or a '1' and loop into state [1]
  read a '(', push the parenthesis and loop into state [1]
  read a 'U', when there is an open parenthesis on the top of stack, push the 'U' and loop into state [1]
  read a ')', when there is a 'U' on the top of the stack, pop the 'U', pop the opend parenthesis following, and loop into state[1]
```

There is a straightforward way to write this automaton in Python. Usually, you need a goto to write an automaton. Each state binds to a label, and going from one state to another is done with a goto. Unfortunately, there is no goto in Python. Howeve, since you have only one state, it isn't necessary and a loop will do:

```
def parse(input):
  index = 0
  stack = [];

  def top():
    if len(stack) > 0:
      return stack[len(stack)-1]
    else:
      return None

  while index < len(input):
    if input[index] in ['0', '1']:
      pass
    elif input[index] is '(':
      stack.append('(')
    elif input[index] is 'U' and top() == '(':
      stack.append('U')
    elif input[index] is ')' and top() == 'U':
      stack.pop()
      stack.pop()
    else:
      raise MySyntaxError("Unexpected char '" + input[index] + "'", index)
    index += 1

  if len(stack):
    raise MySyntaxError("unterminated input", index)
```

This is a PDA with an explicit stack. The previous parser used the program stack instead of an implicit stack, and remembered the number of parenthesis read in the number of recursive calls. This second parser is usefull when you want to check the validity of a string. But it is unhandy when you want to produce a representation of the input, like an Abstract Syntax Tree: they are usually built from grammar and thus easier to produce from the first parser. The first one is also easier to read as you don't have to compute the automaton to understand it.